# How to figure out rising words (or words which are becoming more popular from a list)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was wondering how I can figure out rising words (sort of similar to reddit's rising threads sort option). What I mean by rising is, what is **becoming** popular. What's rising to the top the fastest. Example:

PS: the `-`, `^` and `v` are just how the words moved. Also the `(a)` and `(b)` are not part of the word. I am just showing their uniqueness this way

At 10:00am I have this list, in this rank

```
1. Cool    (a)  -
2. Best         -
3. Cool    (b)  -
4. Radical (a)  -
5. Sweet   (a)  -
6. Sweet   (b)  -
7. Radical (b)  -
```

---

Then at 10:15am (15 minutes later), the order of the list changed.

```
1. Best         ^
2. Cool    (a)  v
3. Radical (a)  ^
4. Sweet   (a)  ^
5. Cool    (b)  v
6. Radical (b)  ^
7. Sweet   (b)  v
```

---

Then at 10:30am (15 minutes later), the order of the list changes again.

```
1. Best         -
2. Radical (a)  ^
3. Sweet   (a)  ^
4. Cool    (a)  v
5. Radical (b)  ^
6. Sweet   (b)  ^
7. Cool    (b)  v
```

---

As you can see, the word `Cool` as a whole is clearly the dropping in popularity. Currently my algorithm (I feel, is fairly stupid, but I can't think of any other way).

The way I am doing it now is:

1. For every word on the list, I count how many ranks it moved up (`+ num`) or down (`- num`) or if it didn't move `0`. This technically gives me a rate. `Ranks moved per 15 minutes`
2. Then if that same word exists twice (like the word `Cool`), then I average the rate.
3. Then I sort it from highest to lowest and I have my rising words.

Though I feel this isn't very good (or even makes any sense). It surely doesn't take into account any historical data either, only the new data it receives every 15 minutes.

My question is, how can I figure out the top rising word, bottom rising word and all the words in between.

Comment: Could you show us what you already tried?

Comment: @devedv I'm just doing this on paper and on excel. I haven't coded anything (I don't expect anyone to write the code for me), just an idea of maybe how I can do it. I've written down in the first post how I am currently doing it

Comment: The first thing to do is to clearly define in a mathematical way what you consider to be "popular" or "rising". Once you have this, it is usually easy to come up with an algorithm.

Comment: The algorithm you describe sounds right to me. About "historic" rising/falling: How should that affect the _current_ rising/falling status? Should a word that was very popular for a long time still be "rising" even though it recently dropped in popularity? If you want to consider a longer time-span, don't average the different 15-minutes-intervals but just determine the delta over that entire interval.

Comment: @Henry I've defined `rising words` as what is becoming popular. The rate which it is moving through the ranks. The higher the rate, the faster it is rising. How would I take into account historical data? So at 10:30am, how would I consider data I had at 10:00am?

Comment: @devedv I don't think that link is what I am talking about.

Comment: @tobias_k Great questions to ask (and things which I didn't consider). `About "historic" rising/falling: How should that affect the current rising/falling status?` This is one thing which I am honestly not sure about and would be open to suggestion. I get stuck when I consider historical data. How can I include that.... `Should a word that was very popular for a long time still be "rising" even though it recently dropped in popularity?` Well no, because technically it isn't moving up the ranks. That word is considered popular, and not rising, because, its static in its rank.

Comment: "The rate which it is moving through the ranks" shows what I mean. As stated this is very ambiguous. Make this statement precise.

Comment: @Henry I'm not quite sure how to make it not ambiguous. Could you give me an example of where it becomes more precise, so I sort of get an idea of what you mean

Comment: One possible way is "difference of ranks in current and last period". Stating it that way, it is clear that there is no influence of historic data (apart from the last period). But it seems you have something else in mind.

Comment: @Henry i sort of understand what you mean. I'm trying to make something similar, like reddit's rising sorting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take into account historical data you can use some function to decrease weight of data for older changes. That function could be exponent, it decays very fast:

```
risingRate = 0
for i = 0:n
    risingRate += e^(-i) * RankChange(curr - i)
end
return risingRate
```

This code uses `n + 1` last records for a word to compute its rising rate.

Coefficients on every step would be:

```
 0: 1
 1: 0.367879
 2: 0.135335
 3: 0.0497871
 4: 0.0183156
 5: 0.00673795
 6: 0.00247875
 7: 0.000911882
 8: 0.000335463
 9: 0.00012341
10: 4.53999e-05
```

These coefficients assign bigger weight for the most recent coefficients. Which is what you might want.

You can adjust decay rate by using `e^(-alpha*i)`.

Comment: @Marshall i updated the answer, if you need another clarifications, please ask.